# getting the wrong timezone android

Tags: android

i am using this function to get the current time on the real device(tested on Galaxy S4):

```
private String getCurrentTime(){
    TimeZone mtz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault().toString());
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(mtz);
    String current_time = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    return current_time ;
}
```

but real time (for example) :

18:48:16

The return value of the function:

14:17:41

*Automatic date* & *time and Automatic time zone* on the phone has been checked !!

but this function works :

```
private String getCurrentTime(){
    TimeZone mtz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+04:30");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(mtz);
    String current_time = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    return current_time ;
}
```

Another question:

When I change the time on the phone, The return value of 2 previous function changes, How can I prevent this? In other words, How can I get **real time** (Without any internet connection)?

Answer (score 1):

In first sample you receive time in GMT because of toString conversion. To obtain your device timezone, just use:

```
  TimeZone mtz = TimeZone.getDefault();
```

Comment: tnx, now How can I get real time?

Comment: The only way I know in such case is to obtain approximately current  time from GPS fixes, that contain UTC  timestamps, that can be easily converted to local time representation by SimpleDateFormat.